# Every $L^2$ function is the divergence of a $L^2$ vector field

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, divergence-operator, hodge-theory

As in the title, I am struggling with the following statement:

For any  $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ there exists a vector field $F\in L^2(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^n) $ such that $f=div F$.

Apparently this should follow from the Hodge decomposition...

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this is true?

Comment: I was told this, but am not convinced... This is used to show that any distribution with distributional gradient being $L^2$ function is a tempered distribution. So the attempt is to say: aha! we have the natural action $(u,div F)=-(\nabla u, F)$. But I don't know how to justify it, since $u$ is only a distribution, not a test function, thus the divergence in the question is not the distributional one. Also this would show that $u\in L^2$, right? But this is not true (constants).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out in another answer, this is not true in general. A simple example is the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if } -1 \leq x \leq 1\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

All antiderivatives of this function are not $L^2$.

However, there are some simple conditions one can place on $f$ to make the result true. To see how this may be done, let's try to construct $F$. One way to do this is to solve Poisson's equation

$$\Delta u = f \ \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n$$

and then set $F=\nabla u$. The solution $u$ satisfies $\hat{u}(k) = \hat{f}(k)/|k|^2$ and we need $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to ensure $F=\nabla u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Hence, a sufficient condition for the existence of $F$ is

$$\frac{(1 + |k|^2)^{1/2}}{|k|^2} \hat{f}(k) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$$

This is optimal for any proof passing through the Poisson problem, but may not be optimal in general.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought about this. If I assume that $f$ is a Schwartz function, do you think it is possible to achieve the sufficient condition you mentioned, possibly after adding a test function to $f$? Since it would be enough for $\hat f$ to vanish around the origin, I would like to subtract $\hat f \phi$ for  $\phi$ a cut-off function, but this localisation on the Fourier side prevents the localisation in space... (I am still trying to make sense of the pairing $(u,f)$ for $u$ a distribution with $L^2$ gradient and $f$ a Schwartz function)

Comment: The only issue is integrability near $k=0$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the function $1/|k|^p$ is $L^2(B(0,1))$ for any $p<n/2$. This means we need $|\hat{f}(k)|\leq C|k|^{2-p}$ near $k=0$ for some $p<n/2$. If $n\geq 5$ then we can take $p=2$ and any Schwarz function will do. For $n=3,4$, if $f$ has zero mean then $\hat{f}(0)=0$, and since $\hat{f}$ is smooth, you get $|\hat{f}(k)|\leq C|k|$ near $k=0$, which is sufficient since $2-n/2 < 1$ for $n=3,4$. For $n=2$ I am not certain and would need to give it more thought.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the statement is false.

If the statement were true it shall also be true in the case of $n = 1$. Take a function $f \in L^2$, then if $\partial_x \, \varphi = f$ that will imply that, up to constants, $\hat\varphi(\xi) \xi = \hat{f}(\xi)$. If you choose $f$ so that its Fourier transform is locally constant around $0$ (something you can always do by Plancherel's Theorem) that will imply that $\varphi(\xi)$ is comparable to $\xi^{-1}$ around the origin and therefore not in $L^2$.